# Is the expression "You will know what I mean" often misused?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> I will give you a clue, it's one word: poetry. **You will know what I**
>   **mean.**

I thought about it and the sentence "You will know what I mean." doesn't seem to be correct, because you are giving a hint to something, but you're not trying to convey a meaning. So instead of saying that I think you should say "You will know what I am hinting at." Am I correct in saying this? What are some better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "You will know what I am hinting at."

This sounds like something [Latka/Foreign Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latka_Gravas)  might say. It is literally correct, but not idiomatic or commonly said.

"You will find out what I mean, soon enough" or "You'll see what I mean" are more common phrases. Then the question is "are they misused?"

The word "meaning" itself can have a very general meaning. Anything hinted at, or outright stated, is part of the meaning. From this wide scope of a definition, once you know what the speaker means, then you understand everything they said.  So, "hinting" is a specific description, while "meaning" is a more general one, but not incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to say you will understand, in time, what I mean,  you'd say 'you'll see what I mean'.

If you're being secretive and teasing someone that you have more knowledge, you could say 'you'll find out soon (enough)'.

'You'll know what I mean' is incorrect in idiomatic English.